# Mac mini 2018 problem with USB pen drive

Tags: usb, bluetooth, mac-mini

When I insert a pen drive in the USB slot of my Mac mini 2018 the Bluetooth mouse and keyboard lose connection. Anyone knows how to solve this?

I have Mojave 10.14.2 and both mouse and keyboard are Apple.

Comment: When your say "pen drive" I assume you mean a USB Flash Drive, e.g. [sandisk usb flash drive](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sandisk+usb+flash+drive&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Asandisk+usb+flash+drive). What type of USB Flash Drive and have you tried any other brands and do you get the same results?

Comment: It sounds cludgy as all get out, but wrap your pen drive in foil (or buy a quality pen drive)

Comment: @Allan, your said, "It sounds cludgy as all get out, but wrap your pen drive in foil" and I just had to laugh because I almost was going to post the same thing when writing my first comment, even was going to suggest a USB extension cable to get it is away from the other devices. :) BTW, Federico, if you do wrap it in foil, make sure the foil is not touching the metal part of the USB connector so as to avoid a static discharge into the device.

Comment: @user3439894 - The "wrap your pen drive" brought back imagery of [middle-school pregnancy prevention slogans](https://www.instagram.com/p/BnUkFXilhKn/)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely Bluetooth interference from radio frequencies.

Your choice is probably to not use a USB or get another device.

> This means that any USB 3 port, cable or USB 3 device can emit radio frequencies that may cause interference with any Bluetooth devices you using in your computer.

([Source](https://www.bluetoothandusb3.com/the-explanation))

Another quotation:

> The issue is that USB 3.0 hard drives can emit radio frequencies that interfere with Wi-Fi and Bluetooth transmissions on the 2.4 GHz band, especially when placed near the antennas in your laptop.

([Source](https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/usb-3.0-hard-drives-can-cause-wi-fi-interference))

Comment: @user3439894 I haven’t got a link at this moment in time

Comment: @user3439894 added source